# MSSQL - Split a field into 3 fields

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a resultset consisting of 1 column and in this case 2 rows the single column [ProductDescription] is a varchar field that hold 3 pieces of information (I didn't design it) i need to get those three pieces of information out into 3 additional fields using a query

before

```
/------------------------------\
|ProductDescription            |
|------------------------------|
|DB1 - DB2 - DB3               |
|DataBit1 - DataBit2 - DataBit3|
\------------------------------/
```

After

```
/---------------------------------------------------------\
|Field1  |Field2  |Field3  |ProductDescription            |  
|---------------------------------------------------------|  
|DB1     |DB2     |DB3     |DB1 - DB2 - DB3               |  
|DataBit1|DataBit2|DataBit3|DataBit1 - DataBit2 - DataBit3|  
\---------------------------------------------------------/
```

I have tried using combinations of Substring and charindex but haven't been able to get it quite right, each part of the field could be any length so using hardcoded offsets doesn't work.

Comment: Is there literally a dash and whitespace between each component?

Answer (score 4):

This isn't pretty, but it works and it does give you what you are looking for, for your specific case...  If you had a variable number of tokens in your ProductDescription, you would probably need to create a stored proc to manage your state while parsing the string, as this would quickly grow unmanageable.

```
create table #table(productdescription varchar(255))
go
/* Demonstrate it working in a 'pretty' case */
INSERT INTO #TABLE (ProductDescription) values ('abc - def - ghi')
go

/* Demonstrate it working in a 'ugly' case */
insert into #table (ProductDescription) values ('jklsaf -mnoa-psdfaqr')
go

SELECT RTRIM(LTRIM(SUBSTRING(ProductDescription, 0, CHARINDEX('-', ProductDescription)-1))) as Field1,

RTRIM(LTRIM(SUBSTRING(ProductDescription, CHARINDEX('-', ProductDescription)+1, (CHARINDEX('-', ProductDescription, CHARINDEX('-', ProductDescription)+1)) - (CHARINDEX('-', ProductDescription)+1)))) as Field2,

RTRIM(LTRIM(SUBSTRING(ProductDescription, CHARINDEX('-', ProductDescription, CHARINDEX('-', ProductDescription)+1)+1, LEN(ProductDescription)))) as Field3
FROM #table
go
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: There's a small bug: returns "DB2 - DB3", "DataBit2 - DataBit3", "def - ghi", "mnoa-psdfaqr" etc in the Field2 column.

Comment: Fixed.  I forgot to subtract my Charindex parameters to get a LENGTH in the FIELD2 case.

Comment: And I had a very similar bug in my answer too :)

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that there are always three pieces of information in your `ProductDescription` column and that the delimiter is always " - " then the following should do the trick:

```
SELECT
    SUBSTRING(ProductDescription, 1,
        CHARINDEX(' - ', ProductDescription) - 1
    ) AS Field1,
    SUBSTRING(ProductDescription,
        CHARINDEX(' - ', ProductDescription) + 3,
        CHARINDEX(' - ', ProductDescription,
            CHARINDEX(' - ', ProductDescription) + 3
        ) - (CHARINDEX(' - ', ProductDescription) + 3)
    ) AS Field2,
    SUBSTRING(ProductDescription,
        CHARINDEX(' - ', ProductDescription,
            CHARINDEX(' - ', ProductDescription) + 3) + 3,
        LEN(ProductDescription)
    ) AS Field3,
    ProductDescription
FROM your_table
```

Answer (score 2):

How about an inline function that takes a string, a delimiter, and what part you want back

```
 Create Function dbo.GetPart(@InString as varchar(1000)
     , @Part as int
     , @Delim as varchar(10))
    Returns varchar(1000) as 
    Begin
        Declare @CurrentPart int
        Declare @i int 
        Declare @j int
        Declare @Ret varchar(1000)
        Set @Ret = ''
        Set @i = 0
        Set @InString = Replace(@InString, ' ', '')

        Set @CurrentPart = 1
        while (@CurrentPart <= @Part)
        Begin
            Set @j =  charindex(@Delim, @InString, @i + 1 ) 
            if @j = 0 set @j = len(@InString) + 1
            if ((@j - @i) > 0 and @CurrentPart = @Part)
            Begin   
                Set @Ret =  Substring(@InString, @i , @j - @i) 
                If @Ret = '' set @ret = 'Weird'
                break
            End
            Set @i = charindex(@Delim, @InString, @i) + len(@delim)
            Set @CurrentPart = @CurrentPart + 1
        End
        if @Ret = '' Set @Ret = 'inconveivable'
        Return @Ret
    End
    GO 
    Select dbo.GetPart('DB1 - DB2 - DB3',1, '-') as Field1
    ,dbo.GetPart('DB1 - DB2 - DB3',2, '-') as Field2
    , dbo.GetPart('DB1 - DB2 - DB3',3, '-') as Field3

    Select dbo.GetPart('DataBit1 - DataBit2 - DataBit3',1, '-') as Field1
    ,dbo.GetPart('DataBit1 - DataBit2 - DataBit3',2, '-') as Field2
    , dbo.GetPart('DataBit1 - DataBit2 - DataBit3',3, '-') as Field3
```

Comment: This function removes whitespace early, so you shouldn't use whitespace characters in the delimiter as it is currently written.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solution.  Assumes that there is no period (.) in the Product Description:

```
SELECT 
    LTRIM(PARSENAME(REPLACE(ProductDescription,'-','.'),3)) DB1, 
    LTRIM(PARSENAME(REPLACE(ProductDescription,'-','.'),2)) DB2, 
    LTRIM(PARSENAME(REPLACE(ProductDescription,'-','.'),1)) DB3, 
    ProductDescription
FROM #TABLE T
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks luke, that is close but not exact.

```
/----------------------------------------------------------------------------\
|DB1        |DB2       |DB3            |ProductDescription                   |
|----------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|Loading    |Trailer   |Albert Moving  |Loading - Trailer - Albert Moving    |
|Unloading  |Trailer - |Moving Staffers|Unloading - Trailer - Moving Staffers|
\----------------------------------------------------------------------------/
```

Answer (score 0):

Personall I would check for " - " and use that as my delimiter instead of just the "-" for the simple reason that many entries can be hyphenated. Substitute the 3 character comination with a comma and essentially generate a CSV (Stage 1) and the Parse the CSV strings into your table.

There is nothing wrong with distictly dividing your process into two outcome-specific operations to achieve what you need to.

Mac