# Split last name and suffix in field

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a last name field that includes suffixes, and I need to split the field into a last name field and a suffix field.  I have tried `charindex`, but am having a hard time with the syntax. Samples of the data are:

```
Miller 
Wilson Jr
Hearne Sr
Horner III
Bond jr
Jones-Alexander
Brown ii
Rodriguez Maldonado
Appleby
```

I am trying to find a reliable select statement in SQL Server to pull this data into another table with the last name and suffix separated.

Thank you for any help.

**Edit** Additional Info posted as answer

> If there is no suffix, I'd like to get
>   the last name into a LastName field,
>   and leave the suffix as Null.
>
> Fortunately, there are no first names
>   or titles in this field, so I won't
>   have to worry about those, just the
>   II, III, IV, Jr , Sr, two part last
>   names,

Comment: What should happen if there is no suffix?

Comment: Similar post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/630907/mssql-split-a-field-into-3-fields

Comment: names are nefariously complex in nature, because there are about 1000 ways a person's name could exist.  here's a blog on it http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DataDesign/parsing-fullname-field-to-individual

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use a CASE statement that checks for the existence of the name suffices you are seeing in your data.

```
CASE WHEN POSITION(' Jr' IN LastName) > 0 
     THEN SUBSTRING(LastName FROM POSITION(' Jr' IN LastName) FOR 2)
     WHEN POSITION(' III' IN LastName) > 0
     ....
END
```

It certainly won't catch everything and you may have to continually tweak it. Your other option would be to introduce a Data Quality tool that can parse name data using known lists of given names and surnames coupled with suffices and titles. Don't forget you may encounter `John M. Smith III, MD`. How are your going to handle that?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your help.  I ended up using a Case Statement to get what I needed.  It seems a bit crude, but looks like it is reliable for what I need:

```
CASE
  WHEN (mytable.L_NAME like '% Jr') Then SUBSTRING(mytable.L_NAME, 1,CHARINDEX(' ', mytable.L_NAME) - 1)
  WHEN (mytable.L_NAME like '% Sr') Then SUBSTRING(mytable.L_NAME, 1,CHARINDEX(' ', mytable.L_NAME) - 1)
  WHEN (mytable.L_NAME like '% II') Then SUBSTRING(mytable.L_NAME, 1,CHARINDEX(' ', mytable.L_NAME) - 1)
  WHEN (mytable.L_NAME like '% III') Then SUBSTRING(mytable.L_NAME, 1,CHARINDEX(' ', mytable.L_NAME) - 1)
  WHEN (mytable.L_NAME like '% IV') Then SUBSTRING(mytable.L_NAME, 1,CHARINDEX(' ', mytable.L_NAME) - 1)
  WHEN (mytable.L_NAME like '% V') Then SUBSTRING(mytable.L_NAME, 1,CHARINDEX(' ', mytable.L_NAME) - 1)
  WHEN (mytable.L_NAME like '% VI') Then SUBSTRING(mytable.L_NAME, 1,CHARINDEX(' ', mytable.L_NAME) - 1)
  ELSE mytable.L_NAME
END
AS LastName,

CASE
  WHEN (mytable.L_NAME like '% Jr') Then 'Jr'
  WHEN (mytable.L_NAME like '% Sr') Then 'Sr'
  WHEN (mytable.L_NAME like '% II') Then 'II'
  WHEN (mytable.L_NAME like '% III') Then 'III'
  WHEN (mytable.L_NAME like '% IV') Then 'IV'
  WHEN (mytable.L_NAME like '% V') Then 'V'
  WHEN (mytable.L_NAME like '% VI') Then 'VI'
  ELSE NULL
END
AS Suffix,
```

Comment: These won't work if there's a space in the last name BEFORE the suffix. Example: "Smith Jones V" Matches "% V", so your code searches for the first space and returns "Smith" - the "Jones" is lost forever. If you search for " V" instead of just a space, you're closer... But with the data "Smith Vincent V" you'll still lose the "Vincent." Instead, use `SUBSTRING(mytable.L_Name,1,Len(mytable.L_Name)-2)` - instead of 2, use 1 more than the length of the suffix (2 for V, 3 for II and IV and JR, 4 for III, and so on).